# sql to view date attendance and leave from work

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date

please help me to solve it.

here I want to display the details of the date on which employees enter and leave work.

*this is my query is still misunderstood,*

```
    SELECT
      *
    FROM

    (SELECT
      e.NIK,e.Name,date(d.Enroll)AS attd
    FROM 
      dvc0004 d, emp0003 e
    WHERE
      YEAR(d.Enroll)=YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())) AS subQuery1,

      (select adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date from
     (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
     (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
     (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
     (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
     (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) 
AS subQuery3,
     
     (SELECT
      a.NIK, a.Name, s.ExcDesc, b.PeriodeIn, b.PeriodeEnd
    FROM 
      emp0003 a, emp0016 b, sys0006 s, dvc0004 d
    WHERE
      a.EmployeeID=b.EmpID AND
      b.ExcId=s.ExcID AND
      a.NIK=d.NIK AND
      s.ExcPay='T' AND YEAR(b.PeriodeIn)=YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())) AS subQuery2
    
      WHERE date.selected_date BETWEEN queryA.PeriodeIn AND queryA.PeriodeEnd 
      AND subQuery1.NIK=subQuery2.NIK
```

in subquery 1: displays the date the employee entered.
in subquery 2: displays the period the employee had been off from work.
in subquery 3: displays all dates according to the date range.

**the desired query result :**

| NIK | Name | Date | Presence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 012 | Rey | 01-01-2021 | Annual leave |
| 012 | Rey | 02-01-2021 | Attend |
| 012 | Rey | 03-01-2021 | Sick |
| 012 | Rey | 04-01-2021 | Truant |
| 012 | Rey | 05-01-2021 | Attend |
| 011 | Yoan | 01-01-2021 | Attend |
| 011 | Yoan | 02-01-2021 | Attend |
| 011 | Yoan | 03-01-2021 | Annual leave |
| 011 | Yoan | 04-01-2021 | Annual leave |
| 011 | Yoan | 05-01-2021 | Annual leave |

this is a Sample Data on fiddleDB:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=57fe8cb377bbd54856abdad32d0d9cec

Comment: What MySQL version?

Comment: And please [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66848549/edit), include sample data... those data that can return the desired result.

Comment: @FaNo_FN : sorry, DB is MariaDB 10.0.12

Comment: @FaNo_FN all sample all table?

Comment: Well.. yes all table but if it's a lot, you just include a few rows of data sample as long as the result can be reproduced. You can also use a fiddle to create schema and insert sample data here : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3

Comment: Also, since it's MariaDB , there's a convenient way to get running numbers using [MariaDB sequence engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sequence-storage-engine/). With that you can generate calendar table with much less query. Like this for example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=9cda42fdfb4b91f3da2b7649b982d87a

Comment: @FaNo_FN https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=57fe8cb377bbd54856abdad32d0d9cec this is data sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand completely what you want.

"The desired query result table" is not consistent with de data in dbfiddle.

Check this query and let me know what is wrong or missing on it (MariaDB, MySql 8.0):

```
SELECT *
FROM

(WITH recursive Date_Ranges AS (
   select EmpID, ExcId, PeriodeIn as PeriodeIn, PeriodeEnd  FROM emp0016
   union all
   select EmpID, ExcId, PeriodeIn + interval 1 day, PeriodeEnd
   from Date_Ranges
   where PeriodeIn < PeriodeEnd)
   
SELECT t3.NIK, t3.Name, t1.PeriodeIn AS `date`, t2.ExcDesc AS Presence
FROM emp0003 t3
INNER JOIN Date_Ranges t1 ON t1.EmpID = t3.EmployeeID
INNER JOIN sys0006 t2 ON t2.ExcID = t1.ExcId
WHERE t2.IsActive = 'T'

UNION ALL

SELECT t3.NIK, t3.Name, DATE(t4.Enroll) AS `date`, 'what presence?' AS Presence
FROM emp0003 t3
INNER JOIN dvc0004 t4 ON t3.NIK = t4.NIK
) AS aux

ORDER BY NIK, `date`;
```

output whit the example data in dbfiddle:

| NIK | Name | date | Presence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Rey | 2021-01-01 | Annual Leave |
| 1 | Rey | 2021-01-02 | Truant |
| 1 | Rey | 2021-01-03 | what presence? |
| 1 | Rey | 2021-01-04 | what presence? |
| 1 | Rey | 2021-01-05 | what presence? |
| 1 | Rey | 2021-01-06 | what presence? |
| 2 | Yoan | 2021-01-01 | what presence? |
| 2 | Yoan | 2021-01-02 | Annual Leave |
| 2 | Yoan | 2021-01-03 | Annual Leave |
| 2 | Yoan | 2021-01-04 | Annual Leave |
| 2 | Yoan | 2021-01-05 | what presence? |
| 2 | Yoan | 2021-01-06 | what presence? |